# Flex - FileReference upload timeout

Tags: apache-flex, http, upload, timeout, filereference

I'm working on a `air` project and I'm using the `FileReference` class to upload a file to a server.

The server side script must receive the file and do some stuff, then reply with an `xml` telling me if everything is gone `OK` or `KO`.

The problem is that, often, the server side script needs more than 30 seconds to complete his task and reply.

If the latter timeout is triggered then the `DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA` event is not dispatched and i can't get back the server response.

How can i get rid of this behaviour? I can't find any timeout setting in `FileReference` class.

Comment: I would think you have to set the timeout on the server side; The server is giving you a timeout, not the client.

Comment: nono, the FIN comes from the client

Comment: The client is giving you the message, but I suspect it's in response to a 408 from the server. Have you used a proxy (like Charles) to see what response the server is giving you?

Comment: Server side gets the connection dropped before it can reply. I'm sure of this.

Answer (score 0):

Which server side technology are you using? as there are option in every server side language for default wait time, which can be increased e.g.(PHP) -

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '500')
```

Comment: the server side is based on the klone server. no timeout occours. i'm sure it's the FileReference class that trigger it.

Comment: Try to put 

ProgressEvent.PROGRESS event which Dispatched periodically during the file upload operation, and see if something comesup.